# Problems running Postgresql query

Tags: postgresql

Probably a very easy question for most of you, but I'm having some problems running this code:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
 userId INT SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 userName VARCHAR(50),
 userPassword VARCHAR(50),
);
```

I usually use MySQL but encountered PostgreSQL in a school work. Why is this code not working for me? The database just gives me a syntax error, nothing else is provided for me. The only thing I changed compared to the MySQL code is auto_increment to SERIAL.
Thanks in advice!

Comment: It's either INT or SERIAL but can't be both

Comment: It should be `userid int generated always as identity primary key`

Answer (score 2):

If you want auto generated  sequential IDs , use bigserial, and the query looks something like this :-

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
 userId bigserial,
 userName VARCHAR(50),
 userPassword VARCHAR(50),
    Primary Key(userId)
);
```